# Limit configuration and platform combinations in batch build for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In visual studio 2010, you can set the configuration (release or debug) and the platform (win32 or x64)for your solution and project build.

I'd like to limit the build configurations combinations so that the user only has limited options for batch build:

Ultimately I'd like the batch build to look like this:
Configuration Platform Solution Config

- debug|win32
- release|win32
- realese|x64

Instead of

- debug|win32
- debug|x64
- release|win32
- release|x64

I'm creating a wizard for Visual Studio which is why I want to do these limitations so that the uesr doesn't accidentally create a debug win64 which doesn't work for the particular program we're creating.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sooo, how do you debug the 64-bit build?

Comment: I don't follow why you'd want to remove a debug build for a valid release build but you can select `Build->Configuration Manager` find the Project(s) you want to remove the config, select the dropdown arrow for the Configuration column, select 'Edit', and Remove the unwanted configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **Configuration Manager**. In the **Configuration Manager** dialog set the **Active Solution Configuration** to the **Release**. Then for each project listed in the dialog, click on its **platform** and select **Edit** then remove whatever you don't want e.g. `win32`.